# Azure App Service download blob "access to path denied"

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, blob

I have an MVC 5 web app hosted on Azure App Service. The application communicates with Azure blob storage and lists the blobs from each container. The application also allows users to download blobs to their local drive. All this works fine using IIS.

However, when I publish the app to Azure App Service, I receive access to this path is denied.

So my question is; how can I enable permissions on App Service to allow write access to a specific folder on a users PC?

I need to be able to download the blob contents to a users local drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you granted the IIS App pool permissions to the download folder, you mean you download the files to the server machine right?

Your server has no access to the user's PC drive. You have to return the file as a result from your controller to initiate download via the user's browser.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by creating a shared access signature for each of the blobs and appending this to the blob URI. This allows direct access to the blobs on Azure Blob Storage for authorised users.